# Custom Listing is separated by categories

Tags: category, product-list

I want to display the products in a separate sub-category for other sub-categories within the listing. Basis rather than display a common list of products they are organized the way it is in this example:

http://www.partypieces.co.uk/busy-bees-1.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton(‘catalog/layer’);
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(currentCategoryId);
foreach ($children as $category) {
   echo '<h1>'. $category->getName().'</h1>'
   $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category);
   foreach($collection as $product)
   {
       $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
       /* Do What You Want With Products
   }
}
```

Try The above this is just a test not been tested.